# Как собрать многостраничный БЭМ-проект c зависимостями на Gulp4 и/или Webpack4?

Tags: бэм, webpack4, gulp4

Я только недавно начал всеобъемлюще осваивать БЭМ-методологию (до этого использовал только БЭМ-нейминг). Мне очень понравилась эта концепция и хотелось бы полностью внедрить ее в свой воркфлоу.
Однако, т.к. у меня недостаточно опыта и я довольно поверхностно знаю JavaScript, мне не хватает знаний чтобы запилить свой "велосипед" для **Gulp4** и/или **Webpack4**. А готовые решения от Яндекс вроде **bem-tools**, **enb** и других специфических решений мне не подходят из-за своей перегруженности и как мне кажется сложности.

Вводные:
1) html-шаблонизатор: Pug;
2) css-препроцессор: Sass;
3) Vanilla JS

Хотелось бы иметь возможность подтягивать данные в pug-шаблоны из **data.json**-файла или аналогичного **data.js**, а также декларативно определять структуру БЭМ-боков с учетом соответствующих зависимостей.

Если совсем коротко, то нужно вот из такой структуры:

### [image: app-folder]

получить на выходе вот такую:

### [image: build-folder]

Мне не принципиально на чем делать сборку, будь-то Gulp, Webpack или их совместное использование, главное получить ожидаемый и предсказуемый результат. Надеюсь, я доступно изъяснялся и смог донести свою мысль.
Какие будут мысли на этот счет ? :)
Заранее всем признателен.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Похоже, что это самое лучшее решение на данный момент, отвечающее моим требованиям:
Ссылка на домашнюю страницу проекта >>> https://nicothin.pro/page/my-start-kit
Ссылка на репозиторий GitHub >>> https://github.com/nicothin/NTH-start-project
Как по мне, автор проделал хорошую и качественную работу и заслуживает самых высоких похвал.
Возможно, кому-то это тоже будет полезным.